# Django: displaying value from a list of lists

Tags: python, django, list, templates, matrix

I have a list of lists

`list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

How do I display the second value from each list in a template: 2, 5, 8?

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for item in list %}
            {{ item[1] }},
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use dot notation to access list items:

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for item in list %}
            {{ item.1 }},
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```